# Order of filtering operations with AND & OR in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-pig

Let's say I have a Hive query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE
    col1 LIKE "%str1%"         -- matches 1% of rows
    OR col1 LIKE "%str2%"      -- matches 1% of rows
    OR col1 LIKE "%str3%"      -- matches 0 rows
    OR col1 LIKE "%str4%"      -- matches 90% of rows
    (...more...);
```

If some of these strings that I'm matching are far more common than the others, I'm wondering what (if any) performance gains I would get from moving `col 1 LIKE "%str4%"` to the top of this list.

The above example is somewhat simple, but if each of these `OR` operations is a regular expression match on a long string, I would imagine the time to perform 3 matches (`str1`, `str2`, `str3`) that fail almost all of the time would become quite expensive.

Does Hive loop through these operations sequentially and break when it determines a `true` match? I suppose it would be worth asking if the equivalent Pig operation works this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

For Pig the following from *[Programming Pig](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#filter)* should clarify:

> Pig will short-circuit Boolean operations when possible. If the first
>   (left) predicate of an and is false, the second (right) will not be
>   evaluated. So in 1 == 2 and udf(x), the UDF will never be invoked.
>   Similarly, if the first predicate of an or is true, the second
>   predicate will not be evaluted. 1 == 1 or udf(x) will never invoke the
>   UDF.

So if each of your logical operators performs some heavy weight operation then reordering them so they will short-circuit on the first condition for 90% of the records should buy you some performance gains.  Note that YMMV for "some performance gains" as it will vary on the total number of logical operations (the example only gives 4, there could be more), the complexity of the regex's being short circuited, and the size/characteristics of the data being matched.